# Windows 10 update does not resume downloading

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

I am trying to update my windows 8.1 to windows 10.
I am updating through Control panel -> Windows Update.
At one point of time updated downloaded 40% of data and I turned off my machine but when next time update started it started from 0%

How can resume from the previous update progress?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Update should be able to find already downloaded files automatically. If you wait a few minutes, did it find the files? If it doesn't work, an alternative is to use the [Windows Download Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

Of course, using the Windows Download Tool will require you to keep your computer on. However, this is an alternative to using Windows Update if Windows Update turns out to be unreliable even if you *do* keep your computer turned on.

Download the tool (either 32 or 64 bit), run it, and select "Upgrade this PC Now". The tool will download the files and install Windows 10.

For Activation, it should happen automatically upon installation and reboot.

If Windows Update does not resume by itself, and you really need the ability to resume upon reboot, the next option is to use GWX (Get Windows 10). The GWX app uses peer-to-peer method of downloading Windows 10 files. The problem is that you won't get to control when it downloads, as it all depends on the available peers. You should already have the GWX app from [KB3035583](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3035583).

Comment: I want a solution which will resume its downloading, does tool support resuming ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the tool does not support resuming. If resuming is not working for you in Windows Update, the next best option that also has "resume" is the GWX (Get Windows 10) app. GWX uses a peer-to-peer protocol to transmit files. You don't really have much control over it like when it downloads, though. I've updated the original answer with this information and some details.

Comment: Much Thanks, I will try doing this and if it works(which i think will) i'll accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same. Go to the windows 10 icon and select upgrade to windows 10, then click okay to begin the upgrade. If you had started downloading earlier to, lets say 40%, then the windows update will recognize this and resume from 40%.